# Is there an iOS equivalent of appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter

Tags: ios, core-graphics, bezier, nsbezierpath

I'm trying to draw a quarter circle in iOS. In Mac OS, it seems you can use appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter but this doesn't seem to work in iOS.

Does anyone know how to simply draw a quarter circle in iOS?

Thanks

Comment: Think I've found the answer... bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two iOS equivalents, one for `UIBezierPath` and one for `CGPath`:

## `UIBezierPath` equivalent

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path addArcWithCenter:centerPoint
                radius:radius
            startAngle:startAngle
              endAngle:endAngle
             clockwise:YES];
```

## `CGPath` equivalent

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
             centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y,
             radius,   
             startAngle,  
             endAngle,   
             NO); // clockwise
```

Comment: Remember that you'll need to covert your NSBezierPath angles (in degrees) to radians for UIBezierPath angles.   (degreeAngle*(PI/180))