# UIBezierPath and NSBezierPath producing different results when drawing arcs

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I have two pieces of code, one of which works perfectly (the iOS version) and the other does not work correctly (the Mac version). I can't work out what the problem is with the Mac version, which uses NSBezierPath, rather than UIBezierPath.

**iOS Version**

I have a piece of code that works exactly as I'd like on iOS using UIBezierPath. Here's the code:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2.0, y: size.height / 2.0)
let radius = size.width / 2.0
let startAngle = angle
let endAngle = 180.0 - startAngle

let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle.radians, endAngle: endAngle.radians, clockwise: true)
println(bezierPath)
return bezierPath
```

It produces the following output

```
<UIBezierPath: 0x7fe348f82910; <MoveTo {42.677669529663689, 42.677669529663689}>,
<CurveTo {7.3223304703363148, 42.677669529663689} {32.914562235881945, 52.440776823445439} {17.085437764118062, 52.440776823445432}>
```

and displays the following image

[image: correct shape]

**Mac OS X Version**

This does exactly what I want, except that it's for iOS. I'd like to translate this code to OS X/Cocoa. Here's what I've come up with

```
let center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2.0, y: size.height / 2.0)
let radius = size.width / 2.0
let startAngle = angle
let endAngle = 180.0 - startAngle

let bezierPath = NSBezierPath()
bezierPath.appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle.radians, endAngle: endAngle.radians, clockwise: true)
println(bezierPath)
return bezierPath
```

(it's almost identical to the iOS code).

The output here is

```
Path <0x600000122800>
Bounds: {{-4.9018102839097546e-05, -4.9018102839077596e-05}, {50.000098036205685, 50.000094758067902}}
Control point bounds: {{-0.18691031775632938, -0.18691031775632855}, {50.373820635512658, 50.37016203886877}}
49.997651 25.342684 moveto
50.186910 11.536862 39.148505 0.191608 25.342684 0.002349 curveto
11.536862 -0.186910 0.191608 10.851495 0.002349 24.657316 curveto
-0.186910 38.463138 10.851495 49.808392 24.657316 49.997651 curveto
38.196255 50.183252 49.422202 39.556558 49.978864 26.027794 curveto
```

with the following shape resulting

[image: incorrect result]

Both code segments were given the same inputs and use the same methods for computing radians, etc. As far as I can tell, everything is the same between the two, apart from the output. It is also worth noting that I am converting each of the paths into `UIImage`s and `NSImage`s after they are drawn. Please let me know if I should post the code that I'm using to do this.

I've also tried using `moveToPoint` to get both pieces of code to the correct starting position (unnecessary on iOS, didn't fix the issue on OS X).

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Have possibly found a solution—perhaps the Cocoa version requires angles in degrees rather than radians? [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704372/is-there-an-ios-equivalent-of-appendbezierpathwitharcwithcenter). Will update when I get the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that on iOS `addArcWithCenter` takes radians for `startAngle` and `endAngle`, and on OS X `appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter` takes degrees.

[Here's the link to the documentation for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:).